# Why does signbit(-0) return 0?

Tags: c, floating-point, sign

From *The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7*, IEEE Std 1003.1-2008:

> The signbit() macro shall return a non-zero value if and only if the
>   sign of its argument value is negative.

Why does `signbit(-0)` return `0`? I just want to understand the logic behind this decision.

Comment: Must use two's complement

Comment: 0 is represented internally as 0000000 (well, in 8 bit), whose sign bit is 0 (hence it returns 0), -1 for example is represented internally as 11111111 (in 8 bit) whose sign bit is 1. This is what you're seeing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In `signbit(-0)`:

- `0` is a constant of type `int`.
- `-0` is the result of negating `0`, so it is zero of type `int`.
- This value is converted to floating-point.
- The sign bit in the floating-point value is zero, so `signbit(-0)` produces 0.

If you do `signbit(-0.)` instead:

- `0.` is a constant of type `double`.
- `-0.` is the result of negating `0.`, so it is a negative zero of type `double`.
- The sign bit in the floating-point value is one, so `signbit(-0.)` produces 1.

The key is that `-0` negates an integer type, and the integer types typically do not encode negative zero as distinct from a positive zero. When an integer zero is converted to floating point, the result is a simple (positive) zero. However, `-0.` negates a floating-point type, and the floating-point types do encode negative zero distinctly from positive zero.

Comment: Does C respect a literal `-0.0` and keep it negative?  I've never had to care before, so i never checked...

Comment: cHao: The base C standard is not strict about how floating-point is handled. Typical implementations, especially those that use IEEE 754, will maintain the sign bit in floating-point zeroes, especially in simple operations. (E.g., I would not be surprised if library routines in some implementations were less strict in sign handling.)

Answer (score 11):

In two's complement, which is by far the most common representation for signed integers these days, there is no such thing as negative zero.  `-0 == +0` in all cases, even bitwise.  So by the time the macro's code processes it, even if it includes `((float) -0)`, the sign is already gone.

If you want to test, you might have better luck with something like `signbit(-0.0)` or `signbit(-1.0 * 0)`.  Since you're not converting from an integer at that point, the number should still have a sign.

Comment: The sign bit macro operates on floating point data only, which is not typically represented in two's complement.

Comment: @StephenCanon: Well.  This is awkward.  :)  Hopefully the fixed explanation covers that.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't.  The `signbit` macro returns the literal signbit of a floating-point datum.  Note the text: "if the sign of the argument" is negative, not "if the argument" is negative.

Footnote 236 in the C standard clarifies:

> The signbit macro reports the sign of all values, including infinities, zeros, and NaNs.

Is this a hypothetical question, or do you have a buggy implementation?

Comment: I'm just learning C and experimenting with various functions.

Comment: The sign bit of `-0` is `0`. It's not promoted to a floating-point type until after the sign bit is lost.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan: right, I didn't interpret `signbit(-0)` as literal program text, but perhaps I should have.